# /var/lib/dpkg/info/shim-signed.postinst: 165: /usr/lib/grub/grub-multi-install: not found

Tags: dpkg

After a fresh Ubuntu install I'm running into this error:
`Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Full log:

```
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 installed shim-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As I can see, this package is to blame:
`shim-signed`.
But it is also a system package so I can't purge it, there is no cached installation file and `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` results in the same log as previously.

Can someone please explain what this `/usr/lib/grub/grub-multi-install` is and how to fix it?

*P.S. Running an ~2017 HP office laptop that still has BIOS for some odd reason. Might be related to grub somehow.*

Comment: The file `/usr/lib/grub/grub-multi-install` is part of the package `grub-common`, this package should be installed on your system. I'd try to reinstall the package (`sudo apt reinstall grub-common`) to see if this helps. Which version of Ubuntu did you install?

Comment: @mook765 Same result. It even detects that one package has to be fixed: `1 not fully installed or removed.`

Comment: It's a strange thing, no idea how to fix this. Since this is a fresh install I'd try a reinstall. Your machine should be EFI compatible if it's from ~2017. If there is no need for bios boot, I'd disable it in Bios settings, EFI boot is usually preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shim-signed/+bug/2012196
...it can be fixed with `sudo apt -f install grub-common/jammy grub2-common/jammy`. Looks like it solved the issue for me.
After it is done, you can clean up unnecessary packages with `sudo apt autoremove`.

Comment: In my case for kubectx I added a dependency on `http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian` even though I run ubuntu, which caused `grub-common/now 2.06-3~deb10u1` to be installed. That is also what is mentioned in the linked bug report. I removed that dependency form my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and did the fix-install command you provided, fixing the issue.